# Difficulty linking proper $var values and db rows in this PHP foreach statement

Tags: php, mysql, variables, foreach

I'm trying to insert a PHP function into a `foreach loop` in order to generate values for each row `fetched` from the db for the `variable $Match`.

The db query itself works properly, and the function which assigns values to `variable $Match` works properly when I test it with hard-coded values, but when I try combining it with the rest of the code in order to use db values it stops working properly. Specifically: 1) It only runs the first IF statement; and 2) If that statement is true, it's adding the same value for every row.

I've uploaded a functional example with hard-coded values to this sandbox [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f1ec75bdd55c795be13fb1ed460356889a2676d4)

*Declaring values for test case:*

```
$User_Waist = "26";
$User_Hip = "38";
$Match = Null;
$waistMatch = Null;
$hipMatch = Null;
```

*Query database & fetchAll*

```
$stmt = $conn - > prepare("SELECT * FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET($User_Waist, Waist_Measurement) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET($User_Hip, Hip_Measurement) > 0;");
$stmt - > bindValue(':Waist_Measurement', $Waist_Measurement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt - > bindValue(':Hip_Measurement', $Hip_Measurement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt - > execute();
$rows = $stmt - > fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Loop through results

```
$count = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $count++;
```

*Adds value to variable $Match*

```
    if (strpos($row['Waist_Measurement'], $User_Waist) !== false) {
        $waistMatch = 'waistFit';
    }
    if (strpos($Hip_Measurement, $User_Hip) !== false) {
        $hipMatch = 'hipFit';
    }
    $Match = $waistMatch.', '.$hipMatch;
```

*Display Results*

```
echo "Size #: ".$row['Size'].";   Fit Matches: ".' '.$Match.";  Waist: ".$row['Waist_Measurement'], "; Hip: ".$row['Hip_Measurement'], ".<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL text doesn't contain bind placeholders `:Waist_Measurement` or `:Hip_Measurement`.

The `bindValue` calls aren't going to work, since there's no placeholder of the specified name to bind a value to.

Here's an example that uses a bind placeholder named `:fum`. Note that this string appears *both* in the SQL text and as an argument to bindValue or bindParam.

```
$foo = "bar";
$sql = "SELECT fee FROM fi WHERE fo = :fum ";
//                                    ^^^^
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(":fum", $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//               ^^^^ 
$sth->execute();
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

This is the SQL text in your `prepare`.

(I notice that there's a semicolon at the end of the SQL text, and that may be causing an error; I normally don't include a trailing semicolon in my SQL text.)

```sql
   SELECT *
     FROM SizeChart 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET($User_Waist, Waist_Measurement) > 0 
       OR FIND_IN_SET($User_Hip, Hip_Measurement) > 0
```

But the point is that there aren't any bind placeholders in that SQL text. When you do a:

```
   ->bindValue(":Waist_Measurement",...
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's essentially saying "Hey! There's a string literal **`':Waist_Measurement'`** in the SQL text of the prepared statement", and saying "in place of that string literal, use this value...".

But the thing is, that string literal does *not* appear in your SQL text. There's no bind placeholder in the statement. (There's not even a placeholder of a different name, I don't see *any* colon characters anywhere in the SQL.)

I'm surprised that PDO isn't throwing an error. Actually, PDO probably is throwing an error, but your code is ignoring it.  If your code isn't going to check the return from `prepare`, `execute`, et al. then you can have PDO do the check and throw the exception for you, by specifying an attribute on the connection.

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

---

Also...

The inclusion of PHP variables `$User_Waist` and `$User_Hip` is a little unusual in a prepared statement. One of the benefits of prepared statements is that variables representing values can be replaced with bind placeholders.

(I'm confused by what you are trying to do, I can't tell you how to fix it.)

Comment: I am confused because I have bindValue statements for both Waist_Measurement & Hip_Measurement:-( Would you mind showing me what specifically I should be changing?